# Disable touchpad when moving the mouse in Gnome

Tags: gnome, mouse, touchpad

In Gnome, there is an option to disable the touch pad while typing, but I'd like to have the same option when moving my mouse. Is this possible? And how to set it up?

Comment: That option is actually [built in `libinput`](http://who-t.blogspot.com/2016/08/libinput-and-disable-while-typing.html) which is used by gnome underneath. Afaik there's no similar option to disable the touchpad when moving the mouse.

Comment: Is there a way to enable and disable it through a script that is somehow hooked to mouse movements?

Comment: Maybe if you used `xinput` to monitor the mouse and disable the touchpad when any mouse events are detected.